# Batch check for multiple file range

Tags: batch-file

i need to check if multiple files chronologically exist in a folder. I am having some issues and hope you can assist me.

There are some invoices that needed to be checked - with number starting from 13073713 to 13106972. The invoices contain a prefix "F" and the credit nots "G" for example "F13106972.pdf" and "G13106972.pdf" the suffix .pdf. What i am trying to do is loop through the folder and output all the missing ones chronologically into the log.txt. What am i doing wrong?

```
@echo off & setlocal
set "Ordner=%userprofile%\Desktop\test"
set "Log=%userprofile%\Desktop\Test\log.txt"
set /a from=13073713
set /a to=13106972
del "%Log%" 2 > nul
for /L %%i in(%from%,1,%to%)do (
if not exist "%Ordner%\F%i.pdf" echo F%%i
if not exist "%Ordner%\G%i.pdf" echo G%%i) >> "%Log%"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dos
@echo off 
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "Ordner=%userprofile%\Desktop\test"
    set "Log=%userprofile%\Desktop\Test\log.txt"

    set "from=13073713"
    set "to=13106972"

    (for /L %%i in (%from% 1 %to%) do (
        if not exist "%Ordner%\F%%i.pdf" echo F%%i
        if not exist "%Ordner%\G%%i.pdf" echo G%%i
    )) > "%Log%"
```

Mainly typo errors. Changed/corrected from your code:

- `set /a` in only needed to indicate to the parser that the value indicated to be stored in the variable contains some kind of arithmetic operation that needs to be evaluated. In batch files, at the end, all the values are strings. Not an error in your code (it works), but not needed.
- The replaceable parameter in your `for` command is `%%i`. All the references to it must use the same double percent while inside a batch file. Some of your references were `%i`
- The space after the `in` clause is needed
- Log file deletion has been removed. All the `for` command is enclosed in a block (parenthesis) and redirected to the log file. If it exist, it will be overwritten.